Global minimum of the function $ f(x_1, x_2) = 8x_1x_2 + \frac{1}{4}(x_1 - x_2)^4 $
I am considering the following problem:
Let $ f(x_1, x_2) = 8x_1x_2 + \frac{1}{4}(x_1 - x_2)^4 $
(a) Find all the local minimum points of $ f $ on $ \mathbb{R}^2 $
(b) Does $ f $ have any global minimum point on $\mathbb{R}^2 $? Justify your answer rigorously.

My Work So Far

For part (a), I computed the local minimum points and found them to be $ (1, -1) $ and $ (-1, 1) $.

For part (b), I know that $ f $ has a global minimum value of $ -4 $, but I am unsure how to rigorously prove this. I believe the proof should involve showing that the function has a global minimum, and then confirming that this minimum value is achieved at the local minima from part (a).


Could someone help me with the steps required to rigorously prove that $ f(x_1, x_2) $ has a global minimum and that it is $ -4 $?

Just apply $f$ to the local minima $(1,-1)$ and $(-1,1)$ and see that $f(1,-1)=f(-1,1)=-4$. Hence, both $(1,-1)$ and $(-1,1)$ are global minima.

Thank you Ikeroy, and I would say the Hessian f is not positive semi-definite for some $x_1$ and $x_2$, so how can I ensure the global minimum exists?

The only points you need to verify the Hessian is positive semi-definite are the critical points, i.e., $\nabla f(x_1,x_2)=(0,0)$. They are $(0,0)$, $(1,-1)$ and $(-1,1)$. The point $(0,0)$ has a non-positive semi-definite Hessian, so this is not a local minimum. On the other hand, $(1,-1)$ and $(-1,1)$ has positive semi-definite Hessian (in fact, the coincide). Hence, both are local minima. Since both points achieve the minimum value, they are global minima, ensuring the existence.

If Hessian is positive semi-definite for all values, it is a convex function, the local minima are global. However Hessian for the two critical points are positive semi-definite, does it mean they are global minimum?

What it means is that they are local minima. However, since $f(1,-1)=f(-1,1)=-4$, then they are both global minima with minimum value equals $-4$. If, for some case, $f(1,-1)<f(-1,1)$, then $f(1,-1)$ would be the global minimum, while $f(-1,1)$ would not.

Let $x=x_2$ and $t= x_1-x_2$, then
\begin{align}
f &= 8x^2+8tx+{t^4\over 4}\\
 & = 2(2x+t)^2 +{t^4\over 4} -2t^2\\
&\geq {t^4-8t^2\over 4}  =: g(t^2)
\end{align}
Since $g$ is quadratic function it achives global minimum at $t = \pm2$.

Thank you nonuser, this is awesome!

Doesn't $g$ achieve global minimum at both $t=2$ and $t=-2$?

Of course @Gwen

Questions (a) and (b) can be solved simultaneously: let $u=\frac{x_1+x_2}2$ and $v=\frac{x_1-x_2}2$. Then, $x_1=u+v$ and $x_2=u-v$, hence
$$\begin{align}f(x_1,x_2)&=8(u^2-v^2)+4v^4\\
&=8u^2+4(v^2-1)^2-4.
\end{align}$$
Therefore, the global minimum, $-4$, is attained when $u=0$ and $v=\pm1$, i.e. $(x_1,x_2)=\pm(1,-1)$, and there is no other local minimum.
